# For each / query doesn't give the right value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table in my database. I want to get `ltotal` value from `leave` table, and then count all of `ltotal`. Here are my query and code I use:

```
$annual_query = pg_query("select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='adam' and ltype=2");

            $annual_result = pg_fetch_array($annual_query);

            if (pg_num_rows($annual_query) > 0) {

                foreach ($annual_result as $data) {

                    $total_annual = $total_annual + $data;

                }

                print($total_annual);
            }
```

There are 3 records in the table leave where `lapplicant='adam'` and `ltype=2`.

Each `ltotal` is 1.

When I tried to run`print($total_annual)` the result is 2 (it must be 3).

Then I tried to `print_r($annual_result['ltotal']`), the results is just 1 (it must be 1,1,1).

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: initialize $total_annual = 0;

Comment: you might want to display count($annual_query) just to be sure your getting three records.  Or $recCounter = 0;  foreach {.... $recCounter++;  ...} print_r($recCounter); to know the actual number of records processed.

Comment: I've initialize ` $total_annual = 0;` after `$annual_result` and call the `$annual_result` = 6. Where should I put the initialize?

Comment: can you write the code in for answer? Difficult to read that.. THank you

Comment: I use count($annual_query) and it showed 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_fetch_array()` returns just one row with numeric and associative keys (same value twice when traversed). You should use `pg_fetch_all()` and traverse or use while loop on consecutive rows.

```
$total_annual = 0;
$annual_query = pg_query("select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='adam' and ltype=2");
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($annual_query)) {
    $total_annual = $total_annual + $row['ltotal'];
}
print($total_annual);
```

or

```
$total_annual = 0;
$annual_query = pg_query("select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='adam' and ltype=2");
$annual_result = pg_fetch_all($annual_query);
foreach ($annual_result as $row) {
    $total_annual = $total_annual + $row['ltotal'];
}
print($total_annual);
```

Comment: It works, but If total sum is the only information you need you should go with Craig's answer. I assumed that code you gave was just an early test that failed (usually total sum is used along with list displayed above and then you wouldn't need to nor shoudn't make separate db query for it - just calculate while fetching/traversing data)

Answer (score 2):

Tamil pointed out the immediate problem. However - why don't you just do this in SQL?

```
select sum(ltotal)
from leave 
where lapplicant='adam' and ltype=2
```

Comment: Well, you still have to fetch the result out of the result object. It just means you don't need the loop to do the addition. I suggest a tutorial in introductory SQL + PHP. Also, consider using PDO.

Comment: so after that query I should use pg_fetch_object?

Comment: `pg_fetch_result ($annual_query, 0 , 0 )` . See the manual. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-result.php